# How to create a program to send an email in VC++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I read a post  [How to send a email in VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597374/how-to-send-a-email-in-vc)

I think the answer from Mark Ransom is simpler for a new learner like myself. He mentions that I need to have a paid version of VS in order to use ATL classes.

My question is whether any free methods can do the same things?

Moreover, how I know whether my VS professional version has the ATL classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly [Outlook MAPI interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815799.aspx). MAPI SDK is a separate download, it should work in any VS edition.

VS10 Professional edition [includes ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx).